# Github Last Commit?

Tags: c#, github, commit, github-api

So iv been looking around trying to find out how i can go to a specified github page and get the last commit value and bind this into a value in my application, nothing seems to make sense and there aren't many if any good examples to base anything on. As well as noone seeming to want to share their knowledge on this topic.

Im trying to get the last commit value only from a github page, and use that as a value in my application, can someone give me an example of how to do this? I am using C# with a WPF project type.

Comment: Sounds like it's probably a WebClient job. Can you post some more specifics about exactly what it is you're trying to reach on Github?

Comment: This seems a bit roundabout, in that since the page is a representation of a git repository, why look at the page and depend on the view it gives which can break with a minor redesign, rather than look at the repository itself?

Comment: Im trying to get the last commit value from the repo itself.. sure, i could look at the version and try to get that value instead as it is kept in a .config file somewhere, however some people might not update that with minor changes, im after the most recent commit value to the repository (last commit: 2 hours ago for example but only after the "2 hours ago" part).. Im honestly not sure how i should be approaching it but iv seen a number of websites and applications that have been able to implement it and i was hoping to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to clone the repository locally and inspect it, you could use <s>[GitSharp](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp)</s> [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki). If that is not an option for you then you can use the github API. The url you are after is:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<repo_path>/commits
```

e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/NancyFx/Nancy/commits

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");

    using (var response = client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/repos/NancyFx/Nancy/commits").Result)
    {
        var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        dynamic commits = JArray.Parse(json);
        string lastCommit = commits[0].commit.message;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in comments, this will couple your implementation to github, so be sure that your app doesn't need to work with other git hosts in the future if you choose the 2nd option.

Comment: Yeah this is something that ill be having on a number of users computers (users of the software) so i don't think cloning the repo locally would be a good idea as then i would need to figure out the relative path/fullpath just to access it..

But that looks like it would work nicely (had no idea about the github api till now) ill try it out and get back to you :)

Comment: Yup.. few changes here and there with the lastCommit string and i was able to retrieve the date of one of the commits (did an example of that github as well as my own) 

As i plan to ensure that i update my version with each feature i add and release.. what would you suggest is the best way to auto-update my application.. create a json file with the application data and compare that value with the value stored on github? (since it would have the same file, just an earlier date for example)

Comment: As stated on the website, GitSharp is no longer maintained: *"GitSharp development is currently on hold because we believe that the libgit2 project and its C# bindings libgit2sharp are far more promising to work on."*

Comment: @Darkshadow It's hard to say without knowing the requirements of your app. You could use [github webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks), some caching strategy, or maybe it is fine to just fetch the data again every time you need it.

Comment: Well its more like a database of scripts to automate things that i put together simply so that people can have a central place to use them, each one is connected and installed via a github, all that works fine, but id also like to have a label for the most recent commit for that script, so that people can use the latest and to ensure it works currently.

Instead of having them download a new version each time i update, i was planning to upload the source or the application to github and allow it to check each time it's opened wether or not it's the latest version comparing itself to github

Comment: It might be worth creating a new question - feel free to accept this answer if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yeah, this helped alot from me not knowing where to start though, so thanks definately fulfilled the criteria :)